# How to remove zero(0) index in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

HI I want to get single record -

If i am using `find` or `findById` this is working fine.

```
$this->User->findById(1); //It works (Without leading zero index)
$this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>1))); //It also works (Without leading zero index)
```

When i am using `$this->User->Query(...)` it comes zero(0) indexing array.

Query-

```
$getUser = $this->User->Query('select * from users as User WHERE id=1');
pr($getUser);
```

Output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [username] => john
                    [email] => xxx@xxxxx.xxx
                    [password] => e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
                    [last_login] => 2014-12-10 20:46:41
                )

        )

)
```

Above query should be -

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
       (
           [id] => 1
           [username] => john
           [email] => xxx@xxxxx.xxx
           [password] => e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
           [last_login] => 2014-12-10 20:46:41
       )
)
```

I am build an application which i am using both cakephp and codigniter script. please help me I want to remove the zero indexing array in CakePHP query.

Comment: Use array_pop, `pr(array_pop($getUser));`

Comment: Downvoted for the lack of resource. A simple lookup of the documentation would have revealed that query() is the wrong thing here.

Comment: @mark try to understand my question i don't want to use `$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array(...)));` or `$this->User->findById(1);`

Comment: No problem for down-voted :( but i need a good answer.

Comment: Why are you using CakePHP then? Use vanilla PHP if you plan on fighting the framework where it makes no sense to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$getUser = $this->User->Query('select * from users WHERE id=1');
pr(array_pop($getUser));
```

Answer (score 0):

Then why are you not using the documented wrapper approach using find?
Never ever use query() when you can avoid it. Leverage the framework and don't fight it.

Either

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', ...);
```

or simply

```
$user = $this->User->findById(1);
// Done
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

The result, as documented, is:

```
Array (
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => john
            [email] => xxx@xxxxx.xxx
            [password] => e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
            [last_login] => 2014-12-10 20:46:41
        )
)
```

Comment: Hey i know that query. i have used `all`, `first`,`count` check my question and ans me on my related question.

Comment: Also i know the use of `list`. I want to perfect answer on my related question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first() method:

```
$getUser = $this->User->Query('select * from users as User WHERE id=1')->first();
```

Or you can also use firstOrFail() method which will thow an exception if fail.

**--UPDATE--**

I have examined cakePHP framework now, by making the following changes, you can remove the zero indexing i suppose.

1- first, please go to lib\Cake\Model and open Model.php.

2- find "function query()" at line 3373 or so.

3- Below this method, we will define a new query function as follow:

```
public function queryFirst($sql) {
    $params = func_get_args();
    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    $results =  call_user_func_array(array(&$db, 'query'), $params);

    return $results[0];
}
```

This may work.

Comment: Getting error message = `Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function first() on a non-object
File: E:\xampp\htdocs\2014\projectname\app\Controller\ChatsController.php
Line: 105

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look

```
        $getUser = $this->User->Query('select * from users as User WHERE id=1');

        $getUser = array_values($getUser[0]); 
        $getUser['User'] = $getUser[0];
        unset($getUser[0]);
        pr($getUser);
```